# ERROR onclick event in javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been having a problem for a while now and I can't seem to understand how to fix it and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

What I have to do is when I click on a link on the website it needs to pop up a calculator and then when I click the off button on that calculator it should disappear again. What am I doing wrong!?!? (Note: calcButton is a link and buttonOff is a button)

```
function showCalc()
{
    alert("button was clicked");
    document.getElementById('calculator').style.visibility = "visible";
}

function hideCalc()
{
    alert("off button was clicked");
    document.getElementById('calculator').style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function main() {
    //store top and left values of calculator
    calculator.style.top = getStyle(calculator, "top");
    calculator.style.left = getStyle(calculator, "left");

    document.getElementById('calcButton').onclick = showCalc;
    document.getElementById('buttonOff').onclick = hideCalc;

}

window.onload = main;
```

---

**EDIT:**

Here's the get style method:

```
function getStyle(object,styleName)
{
    if (window.getComputedStyle)
    {
        return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(object, null).getPropertyValue(styleName);
    }
    else if (object.currentStyle)
    {
        return object.currentStyle[styleName];
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT2:**

Calc button (which is an href)

```
<a href="" id= "calcButton">Calculator</a>
```

---

Also I don't think some people understand what the problem is. The problem is when I click it the calculator turns visible and then back hidden almost instantaneously

Comment: I think you're setting up the `onclick` wrong. Should be: `document.getElementById('calcButton').onclick = showCalc();` and
`document.getElementById('buttonOff').onclick = hideCalc();`

Comment: @Cygwinnian: no it's not. `onclick` should be a reference to a function, while `showCalc()` runs the function and has the value of the return value of the function.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your browser's JavaScript console?

Comment: This script looks fine, I think it has to do with getStyle function and also, cross check id's of controls.

Comment: this works... http://jsfiddle.net/keith_nicholas/XztQV/

Comment: can you post your getStyle method?

Comment: What is the `href` of your `calcButton`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="" id= "calcButton">Calculator</a>
```

This will cause the link to practically reload your page, so to you it seems the calculator appears and then "hides back immediately", because the page has been reloaded.

Add something to the `href` property:

```
<a href="javascript:void();" id= "calcButton">Calculator</a>
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XztQV/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! You don't know how long I've been pulling my hair out for haha.